# Django Clickjacking Protection resp.get('X-Frame-Options') NoneType

Tags: python, django, clickjacking

Problem: User must not view a logon page if already authenticated with our single sign on provider.

Solution: An iframe and javascript display a loading gif until after the iframe has returned a response from the single sign on provider. If the SSO provider response is that the user is currently logged in, Django authenticates the user server side, and javascript redirects the user into the web app. If the SSO provider response is that the user is NOT logged in, javascript replaces the loading gif with the logon form.

Using Django==1.9.9, Python 2:

Our `get` call is decorated with `@xframe_options_sameorigin`, but recently starting returning this error sometimes:

```
2016-09-25 16:38:27,598 | django.request            | ERROR    | Internal Server Error: /accounts/open-id-finish/
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
  response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
  response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/opt/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
  return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 88, in dispatch
  return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/clickjacking.py", line 40, in wrapped_view
  if resp.get('X-Frame-Options') is None:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Where is this error coming from? Was there a change in `@xframe_options_sameorigin` in Django 1.9? How is it possible that our get function is a NoneType sometimes?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is an issue with class definition for Middleware.

Previously this would work: `class myMiddleware(object):`

I'm not sure what has changed, but I think you need: `class myMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):`.  `MiddlewareMixen` is found in `from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin`